# how can I close function for others except cornjobs in php?

Tags: php, cron

I have a function in a php file that a cornjob run it every hours...

but If someone or another robots run it my result gone break.

how can I close function for others except cornjobs?

something like this:

```
if(if is my server cornjobs)
{
   dofunction();
}
else
   echo 'not allowed';
```

Comment: You need to make it clearer how you invoke your cron job (that's cron, not corn ;). Is it via some command line browser such as lynx, or directly via php executable. Protection approaches might depend on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to achive that i suggset that you add a second argument to your cron instruction look like this :

```
/the/path/toyour/cronjob/file/cron.php -- password
```

Then test the argument number 3 ($argv[2]) if it is valid or not

```
$pass = (isset($argv[2]))?$argv[2]:"";
if ($pass != 'your password')
{
  die('Password is incorrect!');
}
```

Then by this method you prevent any user from accessing the script directly because arguments cannot be set from other than internal jobs

Hope this is helpful.